# How to draw a truncated triangle? TikZ or PSTricks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, polygon

I would like to draw the following diagram.
[image]

How do I do it? I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-poly}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}
        \PstTriangle
        \PstHexagon[linestyle=dashed]
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

But this is nowhere near what I desire.

Comment: Could you  give some details on what's not working?

Comment: @Bernard There is no problem with the MWE. It is just that I have no idea how to create the image I desire. Using `pst-poly` package, I can create, a hexagon and a triangle but not how to put one into the another.

Comment: Do you want an equilateral triangle or any triangle?

Comment: @Bernard An equilateral triangle would be better but any triangle would suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to go with `pst-eucl`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}
        \psset{linejoin=1, PointSymbol=none, dash=3pt 2pt, arrowsize=3pt, arrowinset=0.12}
        \pstGeonode[PosAngle=90](0,3){A}
        \pstTriangleSSS[PosAngle={-135,-45}](U){A}(4,4,4){B}{C}
        \pstHomO[HomCoef=0.65, PosAngle={180,0}]{A}{B, C}[F, G]
        \psset{HomCoef=0.35}
        \pstHomO[PosAngle={180,0}]{A}{B, C}[D, E]
        \psset{PosAngle=-90} \pstHomO{B}{C}[H] \pstHomO{C}{B}[K]
        \foreach \s/\t in {D/E, F/H, G/K} {\psline[linestyle=dashed](\s)(\t)}
        %%Translated polygon:
        \pstTranslation[DistCoef=1.5, PointName=none]{B}{C}{D,E,F,G,H,K}[D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,K1]
        \pspolygon(D1)(E1)(G1)(K1)(H1)(F1)
        \ncline[nodesepA=1.3cm, nodesepB=0.7cm]{->}{G}{F1}
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. But the above code doesn't produce the same image on my system. It just produces a vertical line with an arrow and letters placed on top of each other. I compiled with XeLaTeX, fully updated. Thanks for letting me know about the `pst-eucl` package. Btw, is there any way to remove the letter labels?

Comment: I too compiled with xelatex. Did you compile with the  `--shell-escape` switch? To remove the point names, just use  `\psset{PointName=none}` as I did for the translated  hexagon.  I let the points being displayed just to make the code easier to follow. Further, you'll have the possibility to remove all the `PositionAngle=`  which will be useless.

Comment: The code works flawlessly on Overleaf. But I can't figure out why it doesn't work on my system. I tried with `--shell-escape` and without it as well. I've installed TeXLive Full (freshly updated) on Manjaro; it doesn't give any errors as well.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution with `TikZ` but using intersections and shift.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, arrows.meta}

\newcommand\bisec{3cm} % distance from corner to center
\newcommand\myshift{\bisec*2.5} % shifting polygon

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick, name path=triangle] 
        ($(0,0)+(90:\bisec)$) node[above] {$A$} -- 
        ($(0,0)+(210:\bisec)$) node[below left] {$B$} -- 
        ($(0,0)+(-30:\bisec)$) node[below right] {$C$} -- cycle;

    \path[name path=inverse triangle]
        ($(0,0)+(270:\bisec)$) -- 
        ($(0,0)+(150:\bisec)$) -- 
        ($(0,0)+(30:\bisec)$) -- cycle;

        \path[%
            name intersections={of=triangle and inverse triangle,
            by={F,D,H,K,E,G}}]
        \foreach \s in {F,D,H,K,E,G}{(\s)}; % replace \path with \fill and add "circle (2pt)" after (\s), to see the intersections

    \draw[thick,dashed] 
        (F) node[left] {$F$} -- (H) node[below] {$H$}
        (D) node[left] {$D$} -- (E) node[right] {$E$}
        (K) node[below] {$K$} -- (G) node[right] {$G$};
%
    \draw[thick, -{Stealth}] ($(0,0)+(0:\bisec)$) -- ($(\myshift,0)+(-\bisec,0)$);
    \draw[thick] 
        ($(F)+(\myshift,0)$) -- ($(D)+(\myshift,0)$) --
        ($(E)+(\myshift,0)$) -- ($(G)+(\myshift,0)$) --
        ($(K)+(\myshift,0)$) -- ($(H)+(\myshift,0)$) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using  Ti*K*z:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (H) at (0,0)[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,
        minimum size=4cm, draw, dashed] {};
\draw (H.corner 1)--++(120:2)coordinate(U)--(H.corner 2);
\draw (H.corner 3)--++(240:2)coordinate(L)--(H.corner 4);
\draw (H.corner 5)--++(0:2)coordinate(R)--(H.corner 6);
\draw [thick](U)--(L)--(R)--cycle;

\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
\node (S) at (6,0)[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,
        minimum size=4cm, draw] {};
\draw [latex-,shorten >=1.5cm,shorten <=0.5cm](S.corner 3)--(180:0.5);
\end{scope}        
\end{tikzpicture}       

\end{document}
```

[image]